# How to integrate Elasticsearch with sails

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm, sails.js, node-modules

I am new to Elasticsearch, I have created new database in elasticsearch and created entries in it. I like to integrate this Elasticsearch with sails. I am using the version of my sails is 1.0.

I have tried sails-elastic and sails-elasticsearch npm and include those in adapter in datastore file.

But it doesn't allow to lift the sails and it throws error as

````
If you're using Sails ≥1.0, try:
npm install sails-elasticsearch@latest --save```

even I have installed the latest version of sails-elasticsearch and it is 0.10.3 https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-elasticsearch



In datastore.js file

adapter: 'sails-elasticsearch',
url: 'https://[username]:[password]@[server]:[port]/'
````

Comment: Which ES version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Packages you have tried are not updated to support the latest version of elasticsearch and sails.js. I suggest you, use the official JS SDK given by elastic team which is up to date and well maintained. You can find the more about JS SDK [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html)